# Is the complement of a semidecidable (r.e.) language always a semidecidable (r.e.) language?

Tags: turing-machines

Is the complement of every semi-decidable language a semi-decidable language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A language $L$ and its complement $\bar L$ are semi-decidable if and only if $L$ is decidable (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language)).

For example, the language containing all programs that terminate is semi-decidable, as you can run any program to see if it halts.
Its complement on the other hand is not semi decidable, as you cannot have a routine that determines, if a program will run forever or not.